# Update RGB image values from row/column index

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I think I'm really missing something here.
I have a RGB image `image` as a `M*N*3` matrix. I have found some regions in this image that I want to become, say, pure saturated red. My regions come from `bwconncomp` plus other stuff; I have stored the row and column values in two vectors:

```
[index_R, index_C] = ind2sub(*stuff*);
```

So `length(index_R) = length(index_C) < M*N` equals number of pixels belonging to my region, that I want to become red. How to update values in `image` using pixel indexes?

Only thing I could come with is:

```
for i = 1:length(index_R)
    image(index_R(i), index_C(i)) = [255 0 0];
end
```

which I didn't even test yet. Is this correct? Is this the only, shorter, more elegant formula out there?

---

**In response to @Benoit 's answer**

As suggested I tried calling `image(index_R, index_C, 1)`. However, I see two problems here - correct me if I'm wrong:

1. If my image is, say, 5000*5000, and I want to highlight 1M pixels in it (legit, since total count is 25M), `im(index_R, index_C, 1)` will return a 1M*1M matrix (with some duplicates, I guess), which seems quite bad for performance. Is it?
2. In my tests this only works with rectangular regions. I.e., if you have a circle, this will highlight the outer square.

So I come up with a new question: I'm getting `index_R, index_C` from `ind2sub`. Should I use linear indices instead? How? That could be a way to highlight just the pixel I need. Thank you in advance.

---

**Things I've tried**

I tried `im(linear_indices, 1) = 255`, but I get

```
 Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.
```

Trying to split it, say, `im(linear_indices(1:length(linear_indices)/2), 1) = 255`, I go out of memory. Really stuck.

I also tried `im(linear_indices) = 255` and it works perfectly (fast, and highlights only what I need). But it works only on the red channel. How could I get blue and green, since `im(linear_indices, 2)` and `im(linear_indices, 3)` give the maximum variable size error?

---

**My final solution**

Given that linear indices should also cover the second and third channels, I came up with

```
im(linear_indices) = 255 %Red
im(linear_indices+M*N) = 0 %green
im(linear_indices+2*M*N) = 0 %blue
```

If you have any better solution, feel free to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the loop and use simple indexing as follows:

```
Im(index_R,index_C,1) = 255;
```

where you assign a pixel value of 255 to the red channel only. Note that using `image` as a variable name is not recommended since its a function in Matlab.

Here is an example using a demo image:

```
clear
clc

Im = imread('peppers.png');

%// Create dummy linear indices. A square in the image here...
[row,col,ch] = size(Im);

a = round(row/4:3*row/4);

LinIndices = sub2ind([row col],a,a);

[index_R,index_C] = ind2sub([row ,col],LinIndices);

%// Forget the loop. Assign a pixel vale of 255 to the red channel.
Im(index_R,index_C,1) = 255;

imshow(Im)
```

Output:

[image]

If you want only red pixels (pure saturated red I guess :) and nothing else, set the other 2 channels values to 0:

```
Im(index_R,index_C,2:3) = 0;
```

Giving this:

[image]

Comment: If this happens in a loop, instead of doing "imshow" or "image" in the loop, try creating an initial frame with "imgHandle=imshow(whatever)" and doing "set(imgHandle,'CData', newFrameData)" in following frames. This method won't keep puling the figure window to the front, and is also faster.

Comment: @user3528438 I would like if you could help me too :)